# Requesting input: swift 8-bit simulator architecture

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

I am creating a simulator of an 8-bit computer using Swift on iOS. The 8-bit computer has a screen with 25 lines each having 40 characters per line (ie 1000 characters total), and each character can be 1 of 256 different characters (eg A,B,C,1,2,3, etc). The 8-bit processor executes 1 instruction every 5 microseconds.

I have created a function that simulates the 8-bit CPU (ie each time it is called it executes one instruction). And I have created and displayed an array of 1000 SKSpriteNodes that I swap on different textures depending on what character should be displayed.

Questions:

1. Is there an accurate way to run the CPU function every 5 microseconds while still having the SKSpiteNodes update? I have tried several variations of the following:

1A:

```
serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .microseconds(5)) {
  runCPU()
}
```

.. but the timing on this isn't very accurate.

1B:

```
repeat {
  let runAt = DispatchTime.now() + .microseconds(5)
  var done = false
  repeat {
    if DispatchTime.now() >= runAt {
      runCPU()
      done = true
    }
  } while !done
} while true
```

..but the screen (the array of SKSpriteNodes) never gets updated presumably because I am running an infinite loop on the main queue?

2. Is there a more efficient way to display my 1000 characters than an array of 1000 SKSpriteNodes and changing the textures when I need to update the screen?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get timing accuracy at the millisecond level on iOS.  It isn't an RTOS.  You either need to pick a much slower cycle time or you could let the processor run freely.   Use can use [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) to invoke your display update code

Comment: Your second code block could work as long as it isn't running on the main thread.  You could probably optimise that code a little; Don't keep calculating "now + 5 microseconds".  The next execution time is simply 5 microseconds after the first execution time; A CPU's clock doesn't take into account the instruction execution time.  With your current code the next clock cycle is 5 microseconds after `runCPU` is done.